# How do I copy a class and its list members in Python 2.7 and not copy the references?

Tags: python, class, copy, python-2.7

I read this about Python classes ([link](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)) and it seems to be the issue I am having.

Here is an excerpt from my class and other code:

```
class s_board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__board = [[n for n in range(1, 10)] for m in range(81)]
        self.__solved = [False for m in range(81)]

    def copy(self):
        b = s_board()
        b.__board = self.__board[:]
        b.__solved = self.__solved[:]
        return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = s_board()
    B = A.copy()
    B.do_some_operation_on_lists()
```

When I call B's method that does something to the list, A's lists seem to be affected as well.

So my questions:

- Am I not copying the class or the lists correctly?
- Is there another issue here?
- How do I fix it so that I get a new copy of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.__board[:]` creates a new list containing references to all the same objects that were in `self.__board`. Since `self.__board` contains lists, and lists are mutable, you end up with the two `s_board` instances with partially aliased data, and changing one affects the other.

As Raymond Hettinger suggested, you can use the `copy.deepcopy` to (mostly) guarantee that you take a true copy of an object and don't share any data. I say mostly, as I believe there are some strange objects that `deepcopy` will not work on, but for normal things like lists and straightforward classes it will work fine.

I have an additional suggestion though. You call `b = s_board()`, which goes to all the effort of constructing the lists for the new blank board, and then you throw them away by assigning to `b.__board` and `b.__solved`. It seems to be like it would be better to do something like the following:

```
class s_board:

    def __init__(self, board=None, solved=None):
        if board is None:
            self.__board = [[n for n in range(1, 10)] for m in range(81)]
        else:
            self.__board = copy.deepcopy(board)
        if solved is None:
            self.__solved = [False for m in range(81)]
        else:
            self.__solved = copy.deepcopy(solved)

    def copy(self):
        b = s_board(self.__board, self.__solved)
        return b
```

Now if you call `A = s_board()` you get a new blank board, and if you call `A.copy()` you get a distinct copy of `A`, without having had to allocate and then discard a new blank board.

Answer (score 0):

try using `deepcopy()` instead of `copy()`

`copy()` inserts references if it is able, `deepcopy()` should copy all of the members without using references.

Comment: Mike isn't using `copy` from the `copy` module, he's using a method of his own creation on his own class. The trouble is the slice-copy of a list-of-lists. But yes, `deepcopy` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The inner lists are being shared.  Here's an article that explains what is happening:  http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php

To fix the code, you can use *[copy.deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)* to make sure there is no shared data:

```
def copy(self):
    b = s_board()
    b.__board = copy.deepcopy(self.__board)
    b.__solved = copy.deepcopy(self.__solved)
    return b
```